# Why is my DC power supply voltage decreasing when I increase my function generator amplitude?

Tags: function-generator

In lab, we are constructing a power amplifier. We built it first in Multi Sim, ran a transient analysis (picture below), built it on a protoboard and then ran it through an oscilloscope to make sure it ran as intended.

[image: power amplifier]

We set it up exactly as pictured in our schematic, we checked it a million times. For some reason, when we increase the amplitude from the function generator passed a certain voltage, the output of the DC power supply starts to decrease and seems to stop at around 6 volts. The problem with this is that it is now biasing it at 3 volts, instead of 6, at the base. And now is causing it to distort.

Does anybody have any idea as to why the DC Power Supply output would decrease when we increase the function generator amplitude?

Thank you very much.

Comment: The pictures are not readable.

Comment: Sorry about  that Eugene Sh. http://puu.sh/oHAi6/388354a3d4.png ![Power Amplifier1](http://puu.sh/oHAi6/388354a3d4.png) The transient analysis on the right is there just to show that on the computer is is running fine. I should have taken a picture of the oscilloscope but by the time i thought of it they started to close up shop

Comment: What's the current limit on your DC supply?  What current is the circuit drawing as you increase the amplitude of the function generator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called "source impedance". Your power supply is simply not capable of supplying the current that you're asking for. Perhaps it has a "current limit" knob that's set too low.

6V (peak) into 8Ω should require a peak current of 750 mA.

Comment: Thanks. I won't be able to get back into the lab until Monday morning but I will definitely look at the dc power supply's specs and current draw when I increase the amplitude. Is there any possibility that this is happening because they are connected to the same ground?

Comment: Sure, if they weren't connected to the same ground I'll bet the power supply voltage doesn't change at all.  As a side effect, the circuit won't work either.

Comment: You ended up being right. The current was limited to 0.1 A which was forcing the voltage to decrease. I've never had to set the current before in the lab so I had no idea that was an issue. Thanks, again.

Answer (score 0):

Your symptoms would appear to describe classic "power supply droop". Where the circuit is needing more power from the source than it can supply.  You provided no details of your power supply, nor any measurement of CURRENT from the power supply to your amplifier circuit.